# How to fade out all views when switching activities

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity with around 4-5 views on it. It has a white background.
Ideally, I want to fade the entire activity to pure white and then fade in the new activity.
But since color animations are not possible, I've stepped off that idea. The animation that I have made looks like this:

fade-in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="1200"/>
</set>
```

fade-out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="1200"/>
</set>
```

I simply set the animation by adding the following line of code to all my activities:

```
overridePendingTransition( R.animator.fadein, R.animator.fadeout);
```

But here's the problem: When fading out using the alpha value of the activity, the entire activity turns to grey when the alpha value is lowered. This does not look pretty with a white background.

So I came up with the idea to just fade out all views on the activity. My question: How do I do this correctly? By the way, if anyone has a better idea, please feel free to tell me. Thanks!

Comment: I have some questions: Which is the trigger for the activity to become faded-in/out? I mean, how do you start the animation for a particular view? What setAlpha() do you use (the one with int or float argument)?

Comment: The trigger is the switch between two activities. I just override the standard android transition with the last line of code in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cool blog post from one of Android's graphics specialists at Google - 
[Old Views Don't Die; They Just Fade Away](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/09/old-views-dont-die-they-just-fade-away.html)

I'm sure you can use it for your project. Check out the other articles and YouTube vids he has on animation, they are pretty awesome. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to wrap the view in a RelativeLayout, and then inflate a view and add it to the outer RelativeLayout with a background color of 00ffffff, and fill_parent parameters.

Use a handler and runnable to increase the alpha value at set intervals (and invalidate the view) before starting the new activity.  Once the alpha is at 255, start the new activity.  Adjust the speed of Handler.postDelayed(), to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question inspired by the article npace mentioned. You will find my fadeout method below. It uses the animation I already created above to fade out all views that are in the parent container RelativeLayout.

```
RelativeLayout container = findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);

for(int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++)
            container.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.animator.fadeout));

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++)
                    container.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                c.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, fadeDuration);
```